# GCP Permissions Error Only After Deploying Cloud Function (Works Locally)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I am writing files to someone else GCP storage bucket, for which they have made a service account for me, and I'm using the service account key (a .json file) as credentials in my code.

I made a Firebase Cloud Function to run my code, so and when I test it locally everything works as expected. It works when I run the cloud emulator as well.

However, when I deploy the function and try to execute it, I get an error like this in the logs:

```
ApiError: my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object
```

Why might I have permissions locally, but not in the cloud? I thought the service account key should be all I need for credentials here.

Comment: Service accounts require appropriate roles to allow access to resources. Your service account does not have permission to create Cloud Storage objects. Add a role to the service account with one of the roles with `storage.objects.create`: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles

Comment: Can you show how you perform the call and the authentication in your code? And also how do you deploy your CLoud Functions?

Answer (score 0):

- As mentioned in the error message the service account
  'my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't have permission to
  create bucket or add objects in Google Cloud Storage.
- As you are writing into someone else's project, please ask the
  project owner to verify if the service account
  'my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' have the necessary
  permission to write to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. To find an
  appropriate role for the service account to be able to access Google Cloud Storage I would recommend you to go
  through [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles).